# AppHarbor Error .NET 4.5 .asmx has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: .net-4.5, appharbor

I would like this old school .asmx file to work with .NET 4.5 on AppHarbor but its giving me this error which I don't see locally.  Any ideas?

Is it because I recently moved to target .NET 4.5? The rest of the app is fine.

```
.asmx has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested.
```

Here is some stack trace

> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +692
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +48
>
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath) +16

Comment: I haven't tried this but one suggestion is to make sure that you have the 'enable precompilation' check box checked in your appharbor application settings.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, but thanks for the suggestion... In the end I think this was a problem with the dll's in my bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this... I ended up re-writing the .asmx functionality (I only had one anyway) into WebApi which was on my to do list... so I just bumped it up to priority one and got rid of the old technology entirely.

Also of note was that I needed to add a .gitignore file to the root of my project which I ended up doing like this...

```
bin/*.dll
obj/*.dll
obj/Debug/*.dll
obj/Debug/TempPE/*.dll
```